# Copy files from one Repo to another Repo using classic editor in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I need to copy some files from a repo to another repo in same project of Azure DevOps by creating a pipeline using classic editor, could someone help

Comment: We are using Azure Repo no errors while configure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below steps to do that:

1. Enable the option "`Allow scripts to access the OAuth token`" in the
   job options to use the `System.AccessToken` in the scripts.
   [image]

Please note that you need to [Grant version control permissions to the build service account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#grant-version-control-permissions-to-the-build-service).

2. Add a Command line or [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines) to run below Git commands to
   git clone the destination repository to a local directory (e.g
   `destrepo` in this sample).

   `git config --global user.email "azuredevops@microsoft.com"`

   `git config --global user.name "Azure DevOps"`

   `$REPO="$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_git/$(destrepo)"`

   `$EXTRAHEADER="Authorization: Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"`

   `git -c http.extraheader="$EXTRAHEADER" clone $REPO`

   `cd $(destrepo)`
   [image]
3. Add a [File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/copy-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml) to copy files from the source repository
   to the destination repository. (e.g `destrepo`).
   [image]
4. Add another Command line or [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines) to run below commands to push the copied files to the remote destination repository.

   `$EXTRAHEADER="Authorization: Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"`

   `cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$(destrepo)`

   `git status`

   `git checkout -b master`

   `git add --all`

   `git status`

   `git commit -m "Copy files from source to destination repo"`

   `git -c http.extraheader="$EXTRAHEADER" push -u origin master`
   [image]
5. Check the result in destination repo:
   [image]